# Не возвращает страны из ВК

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Всем доброго времени суток.
Хочу вывести список стран,отправляю запрос
Заранее всем спасибо за ответы.

> https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?need_all=1&count=50&access_token=

Но ничего не выводит,в чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам код:

```
$countriesOptions = array(
    'need_all' => 1,
    'count' => 50
);

$countries = vkRequest('database.getCountries', $countriesOptions);

echo $countries;

function vkRequest($method, $options = array(), $token = ''){
    $params = http_build_query($options);
    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/'.$method.'?'.$params.'&access_token='.$token;

$curl = curl_init(); // Начинаем построение curl запроса
var_dump($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // Убираем проверку SSL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // Убираем SSL проверку хоста
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // Устанавливаем URL для запроса
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
return $response;
```

}

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan да,извиняюсь,уже запарился.
А какие возможны ошибки?
Делаю на локальной сборке xampp

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan Включил показ,все так же выводит как и на скриншоте в вопросе.Возможно,что меня вк забанил тип?)
А то я слышал лимиты там бывают

Answer (score 0):

Соберите просто такой запрос, у меня это сделано на js (ниже дам код)

/method/database.getCities
access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
country_id=1
count=7
need_all=0
v=5.62

Как я понимаю - у вас просто не доходит в переменную $token ваш access token (это видно из вашего скрина)

```
var sense = 'getCountries';
var count = 200;
var need_all = 1;
var country_id = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.vk.com/method/database." + sense,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        access_token: 'Access token of your app', // Здесь access_token вашего приложения(!)
        country_id: country_id,
        count: count,
        need_all: need_all,
        v: 5.62
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Токен остается пустым,для вызова стран,он не нужен.

Comment: @tweeker, с апреля 2017 года для открытых методов надо будет обязательно [указывать ключ доступа](https://vk.com/dev/service_token?f=2.%20%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)